# Compare HashMap values and return first key

Tags: java, hashmap

I've got `HashMap`

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("b", 2);
        map.put("a", 2);
        map.put("c", 2);
```

I need to compare values, and if it equals, I need to return first key value `"b"`, but map return `"a"`.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare values"? I am not sure if I misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `HashMap`, keys are not ordered, so you cannot tell which key was first inserted.

Have a look at `LinkedHashMap` for a Map with ordered keys.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmaps are not designed to search for values (i.e, they are designed to search for *keys*). You may want to create a different hashmap for this:

```java
Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add("b");
arr.add("a");
arr.add("c");
map2.put(2, arr);
map2.get(2).get(0); // returns "b", i.e, first element added into the array
```